# explain Adjektive without Artikel and is it optional?

Tags: article, adjective-ending

example

> der schinken
>   rohe**r**
>   feminin
>   die milch
>   kalt**e** milch

is this optional or we forced to use it in some cases ?

Comment: Completely unclear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put case endings to German adjectives if you want to use them to describe a noun. Those endings depend on the case, the gender of the noun, and whether there is a definite article/pronoun/numeral, indefinite article/indefinite number, or no article at all in front:

> der/dieser/jener/zwei rohe Schinken
>
> ein/kein/aller roher Schinken
>
> roher Schinken

In accusative case, for example:

> Sie trinkt kalte Milch.

*She drinks cold milk.*

The adjective declination differs from the other declinations and can be somewhat tricky to remember because of the role of the markers in front of the adjective. Practice is key.

---

You can also use each adjective to describe a verb, it becomes an adverb then. That form has no case ending:

> Sie trinkt Milch immer kalt.

*She drinks milk always cold.*

Another form without ending is as a *predicative*. That one describes the noun as well, but as a statement rather than a supplement. It involves the verbs *sein*, *werden* or *bleiben* (and sometimes other verbs):

> Die Milch ist kalt.

*The milk is cold.*